# D3 - Passing variable to x scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a codepen here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yvgJKB

I have a simple stacked bar chart.

I want to make this into a component so I need to pass in the values to make it reuseable

The x scale function returns `d.date`

```
let x = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(dataToStack.map(function(d){
        return d.date;
    }))
    .rangeRound([0,width])
    .padding(0.05);
```

I want to pass the 'date' part in from a variable

I can do this for the x attr of the bar.

```
let xAxisValue = 'date'

.attr('x', (d, i) => {
    let link = d.data[xAxisValue];                         
    return x(link)
})
```

I also need to pass this into the x scale

```
let x = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(dataToStack.map(function(d){
        //let link = d.[xAxisValue];                         
        //return x(link)
        return d.date;
    }))
    .rangeRound([0,width])
    .padding(0.05);
```

The same square brackets dont work here.

How can I pass in the `xAxisValue` to the x scale function.

Comment: Could you edit the post and clarify what it is you want to achieve? The current codepen displays date in x axis label, what should be displayed instead? 

This portion of the question is not clear: "pass in the a value for the x axis - 'date', let xAxisValue = 'date'"

Comment: I have updated my question, hopefully this makes more sense.

Comment: I think it's a typo. Try removing `.` from the `let link = d.[xAxisValue]; ` and change `xAxisValue = 'date'`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, could you update the codepen ?

Comment: Here's a fork: https://codepen.io/shashank2104/pen/JpNOrj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let xAxisValue = 'date';
```

in line 1 to make the codepen sample working.

And then

```
let x = d3.scaleBand()
.domain(dataToStack.map(function(d){
    let link = d[xAxisValue];                         
    return link;
    //return d.date;
}))
.rangeRound([0,width])
.padding(0.05);
```

It works when I modify it in your codepen sample.